# What are the implicit arguments passed to module __init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following:

ParentModule.py

```
class ParentClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

ChildModule.py

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

If, in `ChildModule`, I mistakenly import the parent **module** and not the parent class, i.e.:

```
import ParentModule
```

instead of the correct

```
from ParentModule import ParentClass
```

I will get the following error:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So just what are these 3 implicit arguments passed to `ParentModule's __init__()`?  What are the 2 arguments `ParentModule.__init__()` is expecting?

How does one take advantage of this functionality?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are both modules in the same directory? The only error I get is: `NameError: name 'ParentClass' is not defined`.

Comment: Yeah, the `ParentClass` and `ParentModule` most likely had the same name in the real code, or the real code had `class ChildClass(ParentModule)` instead of `class ChildClass(ParentClass)`.

Comment: @ChristianDean:  Yes, the real module/class names would be Parent.Parent and Child.Child, but I felt using that terminology didn't clarify the problem.  Feel free to edit the question if you think it would be clearer that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the error message is a bit misleading, because it's ignoring the implicit `self` argument. It should probably say `takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`, accounting for `self`.

If you take a look at the `help` output for the module type:

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(type(sys))
```

you'll see the following:

```
Help on class module in module builtins:

class module(object)
 |  module(name[, doc])
 |  
 |  Create a module object.
 |  ...
```

So the module type's `__init__` is supposed to take up to 3 arguments: `self` (not listed), `name` (the module name), and optionally `doc` (the docstring).

---

That's not what you're passing it. When you mistakenly do

```
import ParentModule

class ChildClass(ParentModule)
```

Python assumes that `ParentModule` is a class with a weird metaclass and uses `type(ParentModule)` to find what should be the metaclass. It finds the module type, and calls it with 3 arguments: the name (`'ChildClass'`), the bases (`(ParentModule,)`), and the dict of the new class you're trying to create:

```
type(ParentModule)('ChildClass', (ParentModule,), {'__init__': ..., ...})
```

This results in a call to the module type's `__init__` with 4 arguments (inserting `self` at the front), and the module type's `__init__` doesn't like that, so it throws an error.

---

For more reading on the details of class creation, see the [Python data model documentation on metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

Comment: Excellent work!  I should have thought to run help() on the module object.

Answer (score 0):

When you import module, the code will load `__init__.py` file in module. 
if you want to utilize init, for example preload modules, you could add code into `__init__.py`

```
model/
    __init__.py
    func1.py
    func2.py
```